# Xamarin.Forms Sharing image AND text

Tags: xamarin.forms

I am trying to share an image and a text both at the same time in xamarin.forms:

```
        var fn = "pic.png";
        var file = Path.Combine(FileSystem.CacheDirectory, fn);
        File.WriteAllBytes(file, Convert.FromBase64String(image));

        await Share.RequestAsync(new ShareFileRequest()
        {
            Title = text,                      
            File = new ShareFile(file)
        });
```

But this only shares the image, the title is just being ignored (well at least in anything except email, where title appears in the email subject line)

How can we fix this?

Answer (score 0):

You could use [DependencyService](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/dependency-service/introduction) to call native share method.

**In PCL:**

```
using System;
using Xamarin.Forms;

namespace ShareSample
{
  public interface IShare
  {
     void Share(string subject, string message, ImageSource image);
  }
}
```

**In Android project:**

```
using Android.App;
using Android.Content;
using Android.Graphics;
using Android.OS;
using ShareSample.Droid;
using Xamarin.Forms;
using Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android;

[assembly: Dependency(typeof(IShareService))]
namespace ShareSample.Droid
{
  public class IShareService : Activity, IShare
  {
     public async void Share(string subject, string message, 
     ImageSource image)
    {
        var intent = new Intent(Intent.ActionSend);
        //intent.PutExtra(Intent.ExtraSubject, subject);
        intent.PutExtra(Intent.ExtraText, message);
        intent.SetType("image/png");

        var handler = new ImageLoaderSourceHandler();
        var bitmap = await handler.LoadImageAsync(image, this);

        var path = Environment.GetExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DirectoryDownloads
            + Java.IO.File.Separator + "logo.png");

        using (var os = new System.IO.FileStream(path.AbsolutePath, System.IO.FileMode.Create))
        {
            bitmap.Compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.Png, 100, os);
        }
        var imageUri = FileProvider.GetUriForFile(Application.Context, "your authorities", path);
        intent.PutExtra(Intent.ExtraStream, imageUri);
        Forms.Context.StartActivity(Intent.CreateChooser(intent, "Share Image"));
    }
  }
 }
```

define the [Fileprovider](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/core/content/FileProvider) in your `AndroidMainfest.xml`

```
<provider
  android:name="android.support.v4.content.FileProvider"
  android:authorities="app的包名.fileProvider"
  android:grantUriPermissions="true"
  android:exported="false">
  <meta-data
    android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
    android:resource="@xml/file_paths" />
</provider>
```

file_paths.xml:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <paths xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <root-path name="root" path="" />
    <files-path name="files" path="" />
    <cache-path name="cache" path="" />
    <external-path name="external" path="" />
    <external-files-path name="name" path="path" />
    <external-cache-path name="name" path="path" />
 </paths>
```

**In ios project:**

```
 using Foundation;
 using ShareSample.iOS;
 using UIKit;
 using Xamarin.Forms;
 using Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS;

 [assembly: Dependency(typeof(IShareService))]
 namespace ShareSample.iOS
 {
  public class IShareService : IShare
  {
    public async void Share(string subject, string message, ImageSource image)
    {
        var handler = new ImageLoaderSourceHandler();
        var uiImage = await handler.LoadImageAsync(image);

        var img = NSObject.FromObject(uiImage);
        var mess = NSObject.FromObject(message);

        var activityItems = new[] { mess, img };
        var activityController = new UIActivityViewController(activityItems, null);

        var topController = UIApplication.SharedApplication.KeyWindow.RootViewController;

        while (topController.PresentedViewController != null)
        {
            topController = topController.PresentedViewController;
        }

        topController.PresentViewController(activityController, true, () => { });
    }

  }
```

}

**In PCL call DependencyService:**

```
DependencyService.Get<IShare>().Share(" ", "Share Image with Text", img.Source);};
```

Comment: I just tested and this on Android, an alltthough i am giving the image source, bitmp is always null and so it crashes.

Comment: @innom Try to use the fileprovider to get the image uri like above.

Comment: can u post an example?

Comment: whats with this logo.png part of the path in the android?

Comment: Also bitmap is still null in android after loadImageAsync